# Problemas con eliminar un array de un Objeto

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Saludos tengo un problemas con un objeto que tiene varios elementos repetidos,pero deseo eliminar solo uno de esos elementos , lo e intentado con filter pero me borra todos los elementos repetidos , pero solo necesito que se borre uno.

```
payload ={id:5 , name:"uno" };
cart =[{id:5 , name:"uno" },
       {id:5 , name:"uno" },
       {id:5 , name:"uno" },
       {id:2 , name:"otro" },
]

var totalEquals = state.cart.filter((items) => items.id == payload.id);
totalEquals.pop();
var withOutProducts = state.cart.filter((items) => items.id !== payload.id);


   setState({
      ...state, 
      cart: [...withOutProducts ,...totalEquals ],
    });
  };
```

Intente sacando array con filtros en donde uno me trae los elementos que son iguales y e quito de ese array 1 y obtengo un array , y el otro le quito todos los items repetidos con el id y los saco después uno los dos en el estado y funciona pero lo que necesito es que no quite de la posición en la que estaba , es decir si lo quito del medio no se pierda la posición de los demás.

Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar con esto me ayudaría bastante

Comment: Intentas eliminar solo uno de los objectos que se repiten o todos los elementos repetidos dentro del array ?

Comment: @Richard de los 4 que se repiten quiero eliminar 1 de esos repetidos es decir mantener los 3 y el otro elemento con el otro id , gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

La resolví de la siguiente manera:

```
payload ={id:5 , name:"uno" };
cart =[{id:5 , name:"uno" },
       {id:5 , name:"uno" },
       {id:5 , name:"uno" },
       {id:2 , name:"otro" },


const removeFromCartOne = (payload) => {
        const value = payload.id;
        const groups = state.cart.reduce((results, org) => {
            (results[org.id] = results[org.id] || []).push(org);
            return results;
        }, {});
        if (groups[value] && groups[value].length) {
            groups[value].pop();

        }

        setState({
            ...state,
            cart: [...[].concat(...Object.values(groups))],
        });

    };
```

si a alguien le sirve, este método saca  de un objeto con varios elementos repetidos uno de esos elementos repetidos por un id.

Comment: No olvides marcar tu respuesta como correcta en cuanto te lo permita el sistema.